# std::thread does not start immediately as expected (c++11)

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following code in my `main.cpp`

```
std::thread t1(&AgentsSourcesManager::Run, &sim.GetAgentSrcManager());
doSomething(); // in the main Thread
t1.join();
```

I was expecting `t1` to start immediately and start along the main thread.
However, this is not the case.  I measure the execution time of my program, repeat this 100 times and make some plots.

See the peak in the following picture.

[image]

Now if I wait a bit after the creation of `t1`

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
```

I get better results. See the following picture.

[image]

(Still with a peak there, but well ..)

Obviously my questions are:

- Why a peak?
- Why I don't have a straight line?

## EDIT

Ok, from the comments I understand by now, that there might be some scheduler  magic going on.

### Here is a working example

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <functional>
int main() {
     float x = 0;     float y = 0;
     std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, stop;

    start= std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto Thread = std::thread([](){std::cout<<"Excuting  thread"<<std::endl;});
    stop = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for(int i = 0 ; i<10000 ; i++)
         y += x*x*x*x*x;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    Thread.join();

     std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_time = stop - start;
     std::cout << "Taken time: " << std::to_string(elapsed_time.count()) << "  "<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Compiling:

```
g++-7 -lpthread  threads.cpp -o out2.out
```

### For Analysis I use this code

```
import subprocess
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

RUNS = 1000
factor = 1000
times = []
for i in range(RUNS):
    p = subprocess.run(["./out2.out"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    line = p.stdout
    times.append(float(line.split()[-1]))
    print(i, RUNS)


times = np.array(times)  * factor
plt.plot(times, "-")
plt.ylabel("time * %d" % factor)
plt.xlabel("#runs")
plt.title("mean %.3f (+- %.3f), min = %.3f, max = %.3f" %
          (np.mean(times), np.std(times), np.min(times), np.max(times)))

plt.savefig("log2.png")
```

### Result

[image]

I think I should better ask: How can I reduce this latency and tell my OS, that this thread is really important to me and should have a higher priority?

Comment: 1. Schedulers generally work at fixed time quanta, especially if all threads are busy in CPU-bound work (so they have to be preempted on a timer interrupt); 30 ms is not unheard of. 2. The timer you are using may have limited resolution (15 ms is not unheard of).

Comment: Why would you have a straight line ??

Comment: How do these pictures show claimed delay between thread construction call and thread routine start? They seem to be completely unrelated. What are those `DoSomething` and `Run` calls?

Comment: It's impossible to say. Are you running under an OS that can do other things while your program is running?  What are AgentsSourcesManager::Run and doSomething()? You could post a [MCVE], but even at that, I doubt that anyone can help without access to your machine.

Comment: Launching a std::thread has much more latency compared to a normal function call, try the bench-marking using a thread pool where the threads are already in ready state.

Comment: thanks guys. Have updated my question.

Comment: Buy the book **C++ Concurrency In Action** and read it! You need to invest time to learn multithreading if you don’t know what is a condition variable. Your question is still poor as it is hard to understand why you would measure the time it take to create a thread.

Comment: thanks @phil1970. Very helpful indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not measuring what you think you are measuring here:

```
start= std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto Thread = std::thread([](){std::cout<<"Excuting  thread"<<std::endl;});
stop = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

The `stop` timestamp only gives you an upper bound on how long it takes `main` to spawn that thread and it actually tells you *nothing* about when that thread will start doing any actual work (for that you would need to take a timestamp *inside* the thread).

Also, `system_clock` is not the best clock for such measurements on most platforms, you should use `steady_clock` by default and resort to `high_resolution_clock` if that one doesn't give you enough precision (but note that you will have to deal with the non-monotonic nature of that clock by yourself then, which can easily mess up the gained precision for you).

As was mentioned already in the comments, spawning a new thread (and thus also constructing a new `std::thread`) is a very complex and time-consuming operation. If you need high responsiveness, what you want to do is spawn a couple of threads during startup of your program and then have them wait on a `std::condition_variable` that will get signalled as soon as work for them becomes available. That way you can be sure that on an otherwise idle system a thread will start processing the work that was assigned to him very quickly (*immediately* is not possible on most systems due to how the operating system schedules threads, but the delay should be well under a millisecond).

Comment: Actually the thread has work to do, as soon as it's "ready". How can I check the status of a thread then? Care to materialist your suggestion in a code snippet?

Comment: It's not important to know when it finishes, but when it can start.

Comment: @Tengis Not sure what you mean. As I said, your example already does the correct thing for the simple scenario of just spawning a one-off thread to do some work, it's your measurement that's broken. If you need more complex behavior, you might be better off using a full-fledged dynamic scheduler as provided by threading libraries like Intel TBB. You can also implement something like this yourself on top of `std::thread` but that is not a topic that is easily covered in the scope of a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: This is not exactly the answer I wanted, but it still gave me valuable information. I solved my problem by just simply waiting unless the new thread starts running and set a flag to true.